# radio tabIndex to navigate using tab doesn't work in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have 2 radio button, I expect I can use tabIndex on reach radio input, so it can be navigate and select the value using the up/down arrow button on the keyboard, but it doesn't work with my code

```
<div>
        {[
          {
            id: '1',
            name: 'One',
            label: '1',
            value: false,
            defaultChecked: true,
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Two',
            label: '2',
            value: true,
          },
        ].map(({ id, name, label, value, defaultChecked }) => (
          <div key={id} >
            <Radio
              key={id}
              id={id}
              name={name}
              value={value.toString()}
              defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
              onChange={e => console.log(e)}
              tabIndex={+id}
            >
              {label}
            </Radio>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xbcqdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tabs are working, but you need to use the same name for both checkboxes so they work as a group, select and deselect accordingly.

```
<Radio
   key={id}
   id={id}
   name="someName"  // render same name for both checkbox
   value={value.toString()}
   defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
   onChange={e => console.log(e)}
   tabIndex={+id}
   >
     {label}
</Radio>
```